# Python Split Length

Tags: python, string, split

Does anybody know why the number of times the substring  ee appears in string weekday is 2 rather than 1. Using `len - 1` fixes the problem but I would like a better understanding of why the number returned is always higher.

The code below should return the number of times chars appears in word without using count.

```
word = "weekday"
chars = "ee"
string_split = word.split(chars)
print(len(chars))
print(string_split)
```

Result:

```
2
['w', 'kday']
```

Comment: ```chars``` is "ee", which is length 2. What's the problem?

Comment: What value did you expect, and why? That part is missing from your question.

Comment: What is the output you were expecting and why?

Comment: len() return the length of your string not the last index. If wou want to access the last index then you will have to use len()-1 since indexing start at 0.

Comment: Sorry the output of the code should be 1 because "ee" only appears in the string weekday once. Using print (Len(chars)-1) will bring back the correct number on any word used.

Comment: The result is correct (len(chars)=2), i invite you to learn more about split() method :https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-string-split/ and length of a list https://www.hacksparrow.com/python/length-or-size-of-list-tuple-array.html

Comment: The code is not looking for the length of chars. It is supposed to return the number of times a word appears in a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`split` is actually splits the string by some separator - in your case `ee`. So when you split `weekday` by `ee` - you've got two strings - `w` and `kday`

I assume you want to count the occurrances of substring `ee` in string `weekday` - you can do it this way:

```
substring = 'ee'
string = 'weekday'
print(string.count(substring))
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. It makes a lot more sense now that I know it returns the value based on the separated strings.